# Passing parameter to php to get specific information

Tags: php, mysql

i have this quick issue please.

I have this code here which permits me to extract a user name and a photo, and when the name is clicked it takes me to this hostess.php file, well, i need to pass the id variable to the hostess.php and save it, in order to get information only for that id..

Here is the code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
echo "<div id='photo'>"; 
echo "<div id='picture'>"; 
 echo "<td> <img src=foto/photo1/".$row['photo'] . "></td>";
 echo "</div>"; 
 echo "<div id='text'>"; 
 echo '<td><a href="hostess.php">'. $row['first_name_en']."&nbsp;". $row['family_name_en']."</a></td>";
echo "</div>"; 
echo "</div>"; 
}
```

How can i just get the id and then how can i save it to the $id variable
Thanks

The table structure is like this:
The table name is called hostess and the field i need to retrieve from hostess is the [id]

Comment: show your table structure in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
echo '<td><a href="hostess.php">'. $row['first_name_en'] . 
     "&nbsp;". $row['family_name_en']."</a></td>";
```

to this:

```
echo '<td><a href="hostess.php?id={$row[id]}">'. $row['first_name_en'] . 
     "&nbsp;". $row['family_name_en']."</a></td>";
```

and in `hostess.php`, use this to extract the value:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

### EDIT

Here is another method to pass variable as `POST`. Again, change the aforementioned line to:

```
echo '<td><form method="POST" action="hostess.php">' . "<input type='hidden' 
     name='id' value='{$row[id]}' />" . "<input type='submit' value='" . 
     $row['first_name_en'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['family_name_en'] . 
     " /></form></td>";
```

You can use `CSS` to style that button as simple text too. And the value can be retrieved in `hostess.php` as follows:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Hey thanks... i know that, i mean i had it this way but i needed to just save the hostess.php, i don't need the URL as hostess.php?id=22

Comment: @GazetaAlmedicus There are always cookies/session variables/temporary-files/$_POST method.

Comment: Hey thanks... it outputs me some <td> /<div stuff... i guess there might be an error with the insertion of the echo..

Answer (score 0):

Add/change this in your code:

```
$personID = $row['id']; #or whatever the field name is
echo '<td><a href="hostess.php?personID='.$personID.'">'. $row['first_name_en']."&nbsp;". $row['family_name_en']."</a></td>";
```

The addition of "?personID='.$personID will send the value in the GET statement, or within the URL.

On the receiving page get the value that way:

```
$personID = $_GET['personID']+0; #add zero to force a numeric value--be sure to scrub your data!
#be sure to do other validation if needed!
```